# Using reflection method instead of switch

Tags: java, reflection, switch-statement

I'm testing reflection method in java. I want to use reflection method instead of switch method to invoke methods. Assume, I have the below class:

```
public class Sample {
public void add(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("a + b = " + (a + b));
}

public void subtract(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("a - b = " + (a - b));
}

public void multiply(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("a * b = " + (a * b));
}

public void divide(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("a / b = " + (a / b));
}
```

then, in the main method, user enters a method name to call a method. But, I don't know how to set a and b parameters in the main method after calling a method. The code for main method is here:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scr.next();
        Object obj = Class.forName("packageName.Sample").newInstance();
        Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(str);
        method.invoke(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've shown the mechanisms for working with parameterized methods through reflection. 
This will work for all of your methods, since they all take (int,int) as parameters.  You'd have to modify the (str,int.class,int.class) parameters of getDeclaredMethod accordingly if you were working with various param types.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scr.next();
    int a = scr.nextInt();
    int b = scr.nextInt();
    Object obj = Class.forName("PackageName.Sample").newInstance();
    Method method = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(str,int.class,int.class);
    method.invoke(obj,a,b);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

(In this example, note that I've modified the read-in from Scanner to accept method name, the first int and the second int parameters from the user through System.in, separated by hitting enter.)